# How do I test the parameters of a context function called within a component function?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, react-context

I've seen a number of examples on how to mock context and how to mock a specific component function call but I haven't found one that does both at the same time. Most cases for properly mocking context suggest using `mount()`, but then that doesn't give me access to the instance returned from `shallow(<MyComponent>).instance()` which I would then use to make the function call. This is an example of the situation I'm trying to test:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    static contextType = MyContext
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
    }
    myFunction() {
        this.context.otherFunction('shouldBecorrectValue');
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this without changing the code under test.

Answer (score 0):

There is [.instance() => ReactComponent](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html) method for the wrapper returned by `mount`. Only works for class component.

> Returns the single-node wrapper's node's underlying class instance.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const MyContext = React.createContext({
  otherFunction: (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  },
});

export class MyComponent extends Component {
  static contextType = MyContext;
  myFunction() {
    this.context.otherFunction('shouldBecorrectValue');
  }
  render() {
    return <div>my component</div>;
  }
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { MyComponent } from './';

describe('69127076', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
    wrapper.instance()['myFunction']();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('shouldBecorrectValue');
    logSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/69127076/index.test.tsx (10.228 s)
  69127076
    ✓ should pass (47 ms)

  console.log
    shouldBecorrectValue

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.804 s
```

package versions:

```json
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
```

Comment: Also, your example doesn't show how you mock the context in the test. Currently, I'm doing this: `context = {otherFunction: jest.fn()}` and `mount(<MyComponent>, {context}).instance()`. Do I also need to use `React.createContext(context)`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I can make an instance, but whenever I do, it seems to give me a `thrown: undefined` error for the test. So I assumed there was some other step I was missing.